# Is it haram to eat an ice cream whose packaging contains an image that looks like Allah in Arabic?

Tags: halal-haram, allah, arabic

I went to Burger King and they had an ice cream whose wrapper had an image that looked like the name of Allah in Arabic.

[image: Allah image on ice cream packaging]

Is it haram to eat an ice cream whose packaging contains an image that looks Allah in Arabic?

Comment: I don't think anyone knows this. Not t be mean or anything but this question is kind of **weird**.

Comment: Didn't they stop selling it like 5-6 months ago?

Comment: @Atata not where I live

Comment: It's better if you don't buy it, regardless of their intention.

Comment: That is not the name of Allah. If you tilt the picture you will clearly see the picture of how it really looks.

Comment: Or maybe you're thinking too much, *from every angle possible*?

Comment: Claiming something 'haram' is a matter of big discussion with many considerations to make, so you can't just label it as haram unless you provide points. The proper question would be `'how to deal with food items/packaging that have name/image that resembles name of Allah?'`

Answer (score 1):

The image actually depicts the outline of an ice cream cone as you can compare below:

[image]

It does not say  "Allah" ( الله )   since ا and ل are not joined like this when writing Arabic.

I do not think that Burger King or their artists have claimed that this is meant to depict anything other than a cone.

So, you should not rely on imaginations about secret intentions. But if you really feel uncomfortable with it then you can avoid it if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

My opinion on all matters of this kind is that **it is in all situations better to avoid such things.**
And it depends on their intention of printing such things, is it accidental or co-incidence or they are doing it on purpose. In all cases **as a muslim you should talk with them and let them know that this is like this and they should change their design immediately.** If it is on purpose, they must be held accountable by law!

### Allah knows best

Comment: As i commented on his question. This is not the name of Allah. if you tilt the picture it is clear what it really is. the second evidence is the picture to the right displaying Allah in arabic. Notice how many pictures exist of the name allah but the one who created the image choose a picture with the name with that style with the circle and so on and then rotated the other image from burger King.

Comment: If that was ACTUALLY same like Allah than that would had been different case, my answer is for the case you are mentioning.